# How to add a conditional statement as an argument to a function in python?

Tags: python, function

I have the following function:

```
def f(loop_condition, count):
    while loop_condition:
        count += 1
        ...
```

This works with a simple True statement. But what in case I want to have my loop condition to be:

```
count < 3
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the condition as a string which you then evaluate within your function. For example:

```
def func(condition, count):
    while eval(condition):
        count += 1
    return count

print(func('count < 3', 0))
```

**Output:**

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the loop_condition as string and then **`eval()`**:

```
def f(loop_condition, count):
    while eval(loop_condition):
        count += 1
    return count
print(f('count < 3',0))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach will be using lambda:

```
my_loop_condition = lambda count: count > 3
```

And then use it like this:

```
while loop_condition(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this is the solution :

```
def f(count):
    loopCount=0
    while loopCount<count:
        loupCount += 1
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `loop_condition` itself a function:

```
def my_condition(x):
    return x < 3

def f(loop_condition, count):
    while loop_condition(count):
        count += 1
        ...

f(my_condition, 0)
```

You can also use [lambda functions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) to generate conditional functions on the fly if they're simple one-liners:

```
def f(loop_condition, count):
    while loop_condition(count):
        count += 1
        ...

f(lambda x : x < 3, 0)
```